# behaviour of binary predicate for stl map and multimap....

Tags: c++, dictionary, comparator

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
struct vals
{
int cods[5];
int sz;
};  
struct myComp
{
bool operator()(vals A, vals B) const
{
    int i=0;
    while(A.cods[i]==B.cods[i] && i<A.sz)
        i++;
    if(i==A.sz)
        return false; //<-----this is the value im changing..
    else
        return A.cods[i] > B.cods[i];
}
};
map< vals, int, myComp> Mp;                 
int main()
{
vals g, h;
g.sz=h.sz=3;
g.cods[0] = 12;
g.cods[1] = 22;
g.cods[2] = 32;
Mp.insert(pair< vals, int >(g,4));
Mp.insert(pair< vals, int >(g,7));
cout<<Mp.count(g)<<endl;
cout<<Mp.size()<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Now, when declare `Mp` as map and put `false` in the binary predicate..
The output is:
1
1

`Mp => map && binary predicate:true ==> output: 0 2`

`Mp => multimap && binary predicate:true ===> output: 0 2`

`Mp => multimap && binary predicate:false ===> output: 2 2`

I thought that the return value of predicate just tells the `stl` whether to put an element either infront of it or behind it. But I don't get how does this effect the size of the map itself..
Please throw some light on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison must implement a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). This requirement is not met when you use

```
if(i==A.sz)
    return true;
```

in your comparator. In this case, all the elements in the arrays the same. The functor cannot return `true` if both its arguments are equal. The map cannot function correctly if you do not have a strict weak ordering comparison.

You can greatly simplify your functor by using [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare):

```
#include <algorithm>  // for std::lexicographical_compare
#include <functional> // for std::greater

...

bool operator()(vals A, vals B) const
{
  return std::lexicographical_compare(A, A+A.sz, B, B+B.sz); // less-than
  //return std::lexicographical_compare(A, A+A.sz, B, B+B.sz, std::greater<int>()); // gt
}
```

Comment: +1 Implement your functor so: **if** (a < b) **then** a is less than b (duh), **else if** !(b < a) **then** a equals b (since you now have both !(a<b) and !(b<a)), **else** b is less than a. If you ever break any part of that, you're likely hosed. Nice answer, sir.

Comment: now i get the exact way of how a functor works.. :) and the link you gave was useful... thanx alot!!

Comment: @nitish712 Glad it helped. I just added an idiomatic C++ alternative implementation for the functor.

Comment: one more thing which i didn't get is i have inserted only two elements into the map..then the predicate must be called atmost 2 times i guess.. but to my surprise it has been called for 5 times!! why is that so?